# Excel : How to display a list if value not equal to zero from another list

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say source data is like:

```
col1   col2
a1     2
b1     
b2     2
c1     1
d1     
d2     2
d3
```

I want to make another list that looks like:

```
col1   col2
a1     2
b2     2
c1     1
d2     2
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this *in situ* by converting your range to a list and then filtering on col2 to not show blanks.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. What if I need the original list remain as it's and have a copy (reference to the list) in another sheet and use the filtering function. How to do that?

Comment: Moreover, I want to use this filtered list as a source for a pivot table. How to do that?

Comment: @Stan: To address your second comment, you can go directly from the original source data straight to pivot table. Hide the 'empty' values by setting 'filter on values' on the pivot table's row labels with the rule 'sum of col2 is greater than 0'.